# Compare test based not value and set CSS style

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have this angular code which sets text color based on true and false values:

```
<td>
  <span *ngIf="user.enabled" class="badge badge-success">Enabled</span>
  <span *ngIf="!user.enabled" class="badge badge-dark">Disabled</span>
</td>
```

But I would like to extend the code to set css code based on string values. Example:

```
<td>
  <span *ngIf="user.status = 'Approved" class="badge badge-success">Approved</span>
  <span *ngIf="user.status = 'Declined" class="badge badge-dark"> Declined </span>
</td>
```

What is the proper code to implement this check and if it's missing to set default css style?

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator in JavaScript. To compare two values, the correct operator is `==`or `===` if you want to be strict. I'm not sure of what you mean by "if it's missing to set the default code". What is "it"? What is the "default css code"?

Comment: I want to implement something like switch case. For example if the searched string is not found to return default value. Is this possible?

Comment: What is the search string? What is "not found". Do you mean "if the user status is null or undefined, then I want to apply the CSS class *badge* only"? If not, what do you mean, precisely? Maybe "if the status is anything other than "Approved" or "Declined", then I want to apply the CSS class *badge* only"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: you are using assignment call in your `ngIf` instead of comparing values.

Secondly: Angular has ngSwitch directive that might be better in your situation:

```
<td [ngSwitch]="user.status">
  <span *ngSwitchCase="'Approved'" class="badge badge-success">Approved</span>
  <span *ngSwitchCase="'Declined'" class="badge badge-dark">Declined</span>
  <span *ngSwitchDefault class="badge">Unknown</span>
</td>
```